# How do I implement the scoring algorithm seen in the weasle program (by Richard Dawkins)

Tags: algorithm, math, genetic-algorithm

Need some advice on a scoring algorithm I'm working on. I'm basically trying to implement the scoring algorithm as seen in the weasel program (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program)

> Compare each new string with the target string " (any given string)
>   ", and give each a score (the number of letters in the string
>   that are correct and in the correct position).

I'm thinking that you could score the strings based on their characters ASCII value but how would I know if the character is in the right position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Weasel program you don't care about positions - you just put the two strings side-by-side and then go letter-by-letter. Are they equal? Increment score by one. Are they different? D nothing. It's basically `L - h(target, candidate)` where `L` is the length of the strings and `h` is the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the two strings.

This is only possible thanks to the fact that the size is fixed so you can align the strings side-by-side. Should the length not be fixed, you would need to use a different string distance measure that allows comparison of different-sized strings, e.g. the [Levenshtein (edit) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: Alright thx! I'm gonna get it to work using equally larg strings at first. Then probobly look more into levenshtein distance!